# Why I get Type Error: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object

Tags: python, sockets

Server code: https://github.com/Ohyo17/project/blob/master/server.py

Client code: https://github.com/Ohyo17/project/blob/master/client.py

```
for fd in outputfd:
        try:
            if roomCount > 0:
                message = messageQueue[fd].get_nowait()
                fd.send(str.encode(message)) #error in here
        except queue.Empty:
            output.remove(fd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `encode()` on the `str` class directly. You should call it on an instance of `str` as such: `message.encode()` ; assuming `message` is a string.

The function's prototype is defined in the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) as:

> str.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
>
> Return an encoded version of the string as a bytes object. Default encoding is 'utf-8'.
> errors may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The
> default for errors is 'strict', meaning that encoding errors raise a
> UnicodeError.